# assigning a static class attribute triggers error on babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to compile a js class file with babel. the class has static attributes which I initialize on the same line. when compiling I get the following error :

```
SyntaxError: src/Requests/URLs.js: Unexpected token (7:20)

   5 | class URLs {
   6 |     //BaseURL
>  7 |     static BASE_URL = "/api/";
     |                     ^
   8 |     //EmailURLs
   9 |     static EMAIL_URL= URLs.BASE_URL+"/emails";
  10 |     static SEND_EMAIL_URL = URLs.EMAIL_URL;
```

I do use yarn for example in an other project an it does successfully compile that kind of classes.

how do I fix this ? google was ridiculously useless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a babel plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

See docs : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: Thanks, but that is for version 7 of babel, I am using the 6.26.3 version,